# Flexible array member polyfill && Vector implementation in C89

Tags: beginner, c

I wanted a polyfill of flexible array members in C89.
So I made something similar, and made a toy std::vector with limited functionality on top of it.
Here is the code:

vector.h

```c
/* Flexible array member example in C89 - Just because we can!
 * It's demonstrated by vectors, but can be generalized.
 * MIT License; see below for the license text.
 * By Scorbie, 2019. */

#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H

#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* We will use a plain array!
 * We just store the header/metadata/other-fields/whatever
 * in the front few fields, the number of which determined below.
 * So the overall picture is the following:
 *   v-- The start of the allocated memory.
 *   v           v-- The pointer returned.
 *  | | | | | | |*| | | | | ...
 *  |<- header->|<- array-- ...
 * If we don't know the header size in advance, we can use another
 * size_t for specifying the header size:
 *  | | | | | | | | | | | | |*| | | | | ...
 *  |<- header->|<- size_t->|<- array-- ...
 */

/* We will going to use this fixed header for our vector. */
struct header {
    size_t size;
    size_t capacity;
};

/* We define SIZE_MAX, because C89 doesn't define it for us. */
#ifndef SIZE_MAX
#define SIZE_MAX ((size_t)(-1))
#endif

/* If needed, increase the capacity of the given header.
 * On success, return the new header.
 * On failure, return {0, 0} to signal an error.
 * I am not sure whether I should raise an error. (errno=EDOM) */
static inline struct header header_increase_capacity(struct header head) {
    assert(head.size <= head.capacity);
    if (head.size == SIZE_MAX) {
        head.size = 0; head.capacity = 0;
    } else if (head.size == head.capacity) {
        head.capacity = (head.capacity > SIZE_MAX/2) ? SIZE_MAX : 2 * head.capacity;
    }
    return head;
}

/* Byte, the unit of all data in C.
 * Just gave it a better name to be explicit.
 * I'm going to use memcpy to copy data byte by byte.
 * This was the only way I found to be C89-conformant. */
typedef unsigned char byte;

#define VECTOR_INITIAL_CAPACITY 32

/* Get the size needed to completely cover the header by items of size item_size. */
static inline size_t header_get_offset(size_t item_size) {
    const size_t header_size = sizeof(struct header);
    /* header_len: how many items needed to cover the header. */
    const size_t header_len = (header_size/item_size) + ((header_size%item_size) ? 1 : 0);
    const size_t offset = (item_size * header_len);
    return offset;
}

static inline struct header vector_get_header(void* vec, size_t item_size) {
    struct header head;
    byte* src;
    byte* dest;
    assert(vec);
    src = (byte*)vec - header_get_offset(item_size);
    dest = (byte*)(&head); /* To make my linter quiet and be explicit */
    memcpy(dest, src, sizeof(struct header));
    return head;
}

static inline void vector_set_header(void* vec, size_t item_size, struct header head) {
    byte* src;
    byte* dest;
    assert(vec);
    src = (byte*)(&head);
    dest = (byte*)vec - header_get_offset(item_size);
    memcpy(dest, src, sizeof(struct header));
}

static inline void* vector_init(size_t item_size) {
    struct header head = {0, VECTOR_INITIAL_CAPACITY};
    assert(item_size < SIZE_MAX / VECTOR_INITIAL_CAPACITY);
    void* vec = malloc(item_size * head.capacity);
    if (!vec) {
        return NULL;
    } else {
        vec = (byte*)vec + header_get_offset(item_size);
        vector_set_header(vec, item_size, head);
        return vec;
    }
}

static inline void* vector_increase_capacity(void* vec, size_t item_size) {
    struct header head;
    const size_t header_offset = header_get_offset(item_size);
    byte* vec_mem_start = NULL;
    byte* new_vec_mem_start = NULL;
    void* new_vec = NULL;
    assert(vec);
    /* Try to allocate more memory with overflow checks. */
    head = header_increase_capacity(vector_get_header(vec, item_size));
    if ( head.capacity > (SIZE_MAX-header_offset)/(item_size) ) {
        errno = EDOM;
    } else if (head.capacity == 0) {
        errno = EDOM;
    } else {
        vec_mem_start = (byte*)vec - header_offset;
        new_vec_mem_start = realloc(vec_mem_start, header_offset + sizeof item_size * head.capacity);
    }
    /* Check for failure. */
    if (!new_vec_mem_start) {
        perror("Error: vector_increase_capacity failed");
        return NULL;
    } else {
        new_vec = new_vec_mem_start + header_offset;
        vector_set_header(new_vec, item_size, head);
        return new_vec;
    }
}

static inline size_t vector_get_size(void* vec, size_t item_size) {
    assert(vec);
    return vector_get_header(vec, item_size).size;
}

static inline int vector_bounds_check(void* vec, size_t item_size, size_t i) {
    return (i >= 0 && i < vector_get_size(vec, item_size)) ? 0 : -1;
}

#endif /* VECTOR_H */

/* MIT License
 * Copyright (c) 2019 Scorbie
 * 
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
 * of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
 * in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
 * to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
 * copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
 * furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
 * 
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all
 * copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 * 
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
 * AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
 * OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
 * SOFTWARE.
 */
```

Here's a small example of a `vector<int>` using it.
main.c

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "vector.h"

int* stack_init() {
    return vector_init(sizeof(int));
}

int* stack_push(int* stack, int item) {
    struct header head = vector_get_header(stack, sizeof *stack);
    int* new_stack = vector_increase_capacity(stack, sizeof *stack);
    if(!new_stack) { return NULL; }
    assert(head.size < head.capacity);
    new_stack[head.size++] = item;
    vector_set_header(new_stack, sizeof *stack, head);
    return new_stack;
}

int stack_peek(int* stack) {
    size_t size = vector_get_size(stack, sizeof *stack);
    return stack[size-1];
}

int stack_pop(int* stack) {
    struct header head = vector_get_header(stack, sizeof *stack);
    head.size--;
    vector_set_header(stack, sizeof *stack, head);
    return stack_peek(stack);
}

int stack_size(int* stack) {
    return vector_get_size(stack, sizeof *stack);
}

int stack_at(int* stack, size_t i) {
    int status = vector_bounds_check(stack, sizeof *stack, i);
    if (status == -1) {
        errno = ERANGE;
        perror("Error while indexing stack");
        return -1;
    } else {
        return stack[i];
    }
}

int main(void) {
    size_t i;
    int* a = stack_init();
    stack_push(a, 3);
    stack_push(a, 4);
    printf("%d\n", stack_peek(a));
    for (i=0; i<stack_size(a); ++i) {
        printf("%d\n", stack_at(a, i));
    }
    stack_pop(a);
    stack_push(a, 5);
    for (i=0; i<stack_size(a); ++i) {
        printf("%d\n", stack_at(a, i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It would be especially thankful if any of these points are answered:

- Standard C89 conformance (Are some parts not in C89/result in UB etc?)
- Performance (e.g. Is it slower than the sane approach; i.e. using double indirection by struct with pointers?)
- Readability (Refactoring / Idiomatic C etc.)
- Maintainance (My current expectation: This would get you fired if you use this in production, but only a little later than the one using only macros.)

Comment: The `inline` keyword is not part of C89. Are you sure you want conformance to C89 and not a newer C standard?

Comment: Thanks for the info! Yes, I would like conformance to C89. (otherwise I would have just used flexible array members in c99) so feel free to nitpick any detail you see as non-C89 conformant. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very well done effort even though I am not a fan of loading .h files with so much inline code.

---

- Standard C89 conformance (Are some parts not in C89/result in UB etc?)

Good to have used `unsigned char`.

Only UB I see is with pathological `size == 0` leads to `/0`

---

- Performance (e.g. Is it slower than the sane approach; i.e. using double indirection by struct with pointers?)

**Consider space performance**

An `VECTOR_INITIAL_CAPACITY 32` would be fairly piggish if code had a largest array of *vectors*.  I'd start with 0 or pass into `vector_init()` the initial size.

**Correct function?**

In `vector_increase_capacity()`, I have doubts that after code sets `errno = EDOM;` the rest of code is correct.  Should not code avoid the following `{ new_vec = new_vec_mem_start + header_offset; vector_set_header(new_vec, item_size, head); ... }`?

---

- Readability (Refactoring / Idiomatic C etc.)

**why `dest`**

Unclear why extra code.  Suggested simplification.

```
// byte* dest;
// dest = (byte*)(&head); /* To make my linter quiet and be explicit */
// memcpy(dest, src, sizeof(struct header));
memcpy(&head, src, sizeof *head);
```

**unneeded `else`**

```
if (!vec) {
    return NULL;
// } else {
}
    vec = (byte*)vec + header_get_offset(item_size);
    vector_set_header(vec, item_size, head);
    return vec;
// }
```

---

- Maintenance (My current expectation: This would get you fired if you use this in production, but only a little later than the one using only macros.)

**Post C89**

Good this code tests for prior `SIZE_MAX` as perhaps another .h file made it or maybe code is now using C99

**Collisions**

Avoid using name space in an unexpected fashion.

Inside `vector.h`, I would not expect to find a `struct` named `header`.  I recommend to use `vector` or `vector_header`.

This include function names like `header_get_offset()`.  Better to uniformly start with `vector`.

To define `byte` as `typedef unsigned char byte;` in a .h file  is fairly brazen to assume some other .h and application did not define it, perhaps a bit differently.  I'd recommend simple using `unsigned char`.

**Does `#include "vector.h"` stand on its own?**

As a test to insure `"vector.h"` includes itself, needed include files, try `"vector.h"` first.

```
#include "vector.h"
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
// #include "vector.h"
```

**IANAL but**

Copyright notices need to be obvious, not buried at the end of code.

**No free**

I'd a function to call to free all allocations.  Perhaps `void stack_uninit(void* vec)`?

Comment: Wow! A big THANK YOU for the detailed and clear explanation!
Could you elaborate on static inline, whether it's bad style or personal preference and why?

Comment: I see long `inline` functions as [repetitive code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_bloat), rarely improving performance that much (and certainly not [big - 0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)).  For performance improvements, focusing on high level simplifications is more worth my time.

Answer (score 0):

Update: here's the edited code thanks to the feedback!

````c
/* Flexible array member example in C89 - Just because we can!
 * It's demonstrated by vectors, but can be generalized.
 * By Scorbie, 2019.
 * Reviewed by StackExchange users "chux - Reinstate Monica" and "Björn Lindqvist":
 * https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/234514
 * 
 * MIT License
 * Copyright (c) 2019 Scorbie
 * Copyright (c) 2019 chux - Reinstate Monica
 * 
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
 * of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
 * in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
 * to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
 * copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
 * furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
 * 
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all
 * copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 * 
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
 * AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
 * OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
 * SOFTWARE.
 */

#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H

#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* We will use a plain array!
 * We just store the header/metadata/other-fields/whatever
 * in the front few fields, the number of which determined below.
 * So the overall picture is the following:
 *   v-- The start of the allocated memory.
 *   v           v-- The pointer returned.
 *  | | | | | | |*| | | | | ...
 *  |<- header->|<- array-- ...
 * If we don't know the header size in advance, we can use another
 * size_t for specifying the header size:
 *  | | | | | | | | | | | | |*| | | | | ...
 *  |<- header->|<- size_t->|<- array-- ...
 * */

/* We will going to use this fixed header for our vector. */
struct vector_header {
    size_t size;
    size_t capacity;
};

/* We define SIZE_MAX, because C89 doesn't define it for us. */
#ifndef SIZE_MAX
#define SIZE_MAX ((size_t)(-1))
#endif

/* Get the size needed to completely cover the header by items of size item_size. */
size_t vector_header_get_offset(size_t item_size) {
    const size_t header_size = sizeof(struct vector_header);
    /* header_len: how many items needed to cover the header. */
    const size_t header_len = (header_size/item_size) + ((header_size%item_size) ? 1 : 0);
    const size_t offset = (item_size * header_len);
    return offset;
}

void* vector_get_mem_start(void* vec, size_t item_size) {
    assert(vec);
    return (unsigned char*)vec - vector_header_get_offset(item_size);
}

struct vector_header vector_get_header(void* vec, size_t item_size) {
    struct vector_header header;
    unsigned char* src = vector_get_mem_start(vec, item_size);
    memcpy(&header, src, sizeof header);
    return header;
}

void vector_set_header(void* vec, size_t item_size, struct vector_header header) {
    unsigned char* dest = vector_get_mem_start(vec, item_size);
    memcpy(dest, &header, sizeof header);
}

/* Initialize vector with the given initial_capacity. 
 * Initial capacity should be >= 1. */
void* vector_init(size_t item_size, size_t initial_capacity) {
    struct vector_header header = {0, initial_capacity};
    void* vec;
    /* Assertions to prevent divide-by-0 and overflows */
    assert(item_size);
    assert(initial_capacity != 0 && initial_capacity < (SIZE_MAX/item_size));
    vec = malloc(initial_capacity * item_size);
    if (!vec) { return NULL; }
    vec = (unsigned char*)vec + vector_header_get_offset(item_size);
    vector_set_header(vec, item_size, header);
    return vec;
}

/* If needed, increase the capacity of the given header.
 * On success, return the new header.
 * On failure, return {0, 0} to signal an error. */
struct vector_header vector_header_increase_capacity(struct vector_header header) {
    assert(header.size <= header.capacity);
    if (header.size == SIZE_MAX) {
        /* No more memory, set it to error value */
        header.size = header.capacity = 0;
    } else if (header.size == header.capacity) {
        header.capacity = (header.capacity >= SIZE_MAX/2) ? SIZE_MAX : (2 * header.capacity);
    }
    return header;
}

void* vector_increase_capacity(void* vec, size_t item_size) {
    struct vector_header header;
    const size_t header_offset = vector_header_get_offset(item_size);
    void* vec_mem_start = vector_get_mem_start(vec, item_size);
    void* new_vec_mem_start = vec_mem_start;
    assert(vec);
    assert(item_size);
    assert(header_offset);
    /* Try to allocate more memory with overflow checks. */
    header = vector_header_increase_capacity(vector_get_header(vec, item_size));
    if (header.capacity == 0 || header.capacity > (SIZE_MAX-header_offset)/(item_size)) {
        errno = EDOM;
        perror("Error: vector_increase_capacity failed");
        return NULL;
    }
    new_vec_mem_start = realloc(vec_mem_start, header_offset + item_size * header.capacity);
    /* Check for failure. */
    if (!new_vec_mem_start) {
        perror("Error: vector_increase_capacity failed");
        return NULL;
    } else {
        void* new_vec = (unsigned char*)new_vec_mem_start + header_offset;
        vector_set_header(new_vec, item_size, header);
        return new_vec;
    }
}

int vector_is_out_of_bounds(void* vec, size_t item_size, size_t i) {
    return (i > vector_get_header(vec, item_size).size);
}

void vector_free(void* vec, size_t item_size) {
    void* vec_mem_start = vector_get_mem_start(vec, item_size);
    free(vec_mem_start);
}

#endif /* VECTOR_H */
```
````